# Combining multiple RegEx expressions to restrict passwords

Tags: regex

I have a need to put a RegEx expression over a property in a model on a MVC website that I'm working on.

The different pieces of the expression make sense to me individually, but I can't figure out how to form them together.

I need to be able to restrict input to letters, capital letters, numbers, and the symbols @ . _ -

I then need to ensure that the following criteria is met by the user's input

1. Input must contain 1 capital letter
2. Input must contain 1 lowercase letter
3. Input must contain 1 number
4. Input must contain one of the 4 symbols that are permitted.

I've tried

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@-_.])[A-Za-z\\d@-_.]{8,}"
```

But it ends up letting the password not include one of the 4 symbols.

Comment: What are those quotation marks? Why you escaped backslash in `\d`? What RegEx engine you're working with?

Comment: I copied this from a RegEx annotation in a MVC project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the - in your regex for special characters.
Updated regex:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@\-_.])[A-Za-z\\d@\-_.]{8,}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`[@-_.]` matches a period (`.`) or any character in the range `@` to `_`.  That includes all the uppercase ASCII letters plus the square brackets, backslash, caret (`^`), and of course, `@` and `_`.  To match a literal hyphen, you either escape the hyphen with a backslash (`[@\-_.]`) or move it to the end of the list (`[@_.-]`).